# Error : screenSize|smallestScreenSize android studio Target SDK 23

Tags: android, heyzap

I'm trying to integrate HeyZap ads into my app but I keep getting this error on build : Error:screenSize|smallestScreenSize).

I've searched on it and I found that it's target sdk error which should be at least 13 but here I'm using SDK 23 .

Here is my Manifest file :

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.celebria">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:name="com.celebria.MyApplication">

        <activity
            android:name=".ActivitySplash"
            android:theme="@style/AppThemeLogin"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".Tutorial"
            android:theme="@style/AppThemeLogin"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />

        <activity
            android:name=".ActivityLogin"
            android:theme="@style/AppThemeLogin"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />

        <receiver
            android:name=".AlarmReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:process=":remote"
            android:exported="true"/>
        <receiver
            android:name=".BootReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name=".DownloadService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:stopWithTask="false"
            android:exported="true"/>

        <activity
            android:name=".Home"
            android:theme="@style/AppThemeLogin"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />

        <activity
            android:name=".ActivityCreateAccount"
            android:theme="@style/AppThemeLogin"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />

        <activity
            android:name=".ActivityActiveTrivia"
            android:theme="@style/AppThemeLogin"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />

        <activity
            android:name=".ActivityMatchUp"
            android:theme="@style/AppThemeLogin"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />

        <activity
            android:name=".ActivityQuestionAnswer"
            android:theme="@style/AppThemeLogin"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />

        <activity
            android:name=".ActivityWinner"
            android:theme="@style/AppThemeLogin"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />

        <activity android:name=".CreateAccount"
            android:theme="@style/AppThemeLogin"/>

        <activity android:name=".ActivityForgotPassword"
            android:theme="@style/AppThemeLogin"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />


        <!-- Google Play Services -->
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>

        <!-- Fyber Marketplace -->
        <activity android:name="com.heyzap.sdk.ads.HeyzapIncentivizedActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" />
        <activity android:name="com.heyzap.sdk.ads.HeyzapInterstitialActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
        <activity android:name="com.heyzap.sdk.ads.MediationTestActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.fyber.ads.ofw.OfferWallUnityActivity" android:configChanges="orientation" />
        <service android:name="com.fyber.cache.CacheVideoDownloadService" android:exported="false" />
        <meta-data android:name="FYBVideoPlayerOptionCloseButtonDelay" android:value="-1" />


    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here is my build.gradle file :

```html
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.celebria"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
repositories {

    mavenCentral()

    maven {
        name "Fyber's maven repo"
        url "https://fyber.bintray.com/maven"
    }
    flatDir {
        dirs "libs"
    }

}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.0.1'
    compile'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.wang.avi:library:2.1.3'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.0'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    compile 'jp.wasabeef:blurry:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.2.0'
    compile 'me.relex:circleindicator:1.2.2@aar'
    compile(name:'heyzap-unified-platform-10.3.0', ext:'aar')
}
```

This is a picture of the error :

[image]

and this is the link I've been following : https://developers.heyzap.com/docs/android_sdk_setup_and_requirements

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue?

Comment: I've tried plenty of solutions but nothing worked, removing it made the error gone.

Comment: I have the same problem in my code, although I don't use HeyZap. No idea how to remove it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
```

screenSize & smallestScreenSize attributes are not available in SDK 10.They are available from API level 13.

For more details: 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config

Answer (score 1):

My issue was specific to my setup. I had set my compiler flags to have `--stacktrace --debug` and when I took that off (made it empty) then things worked as expected.

Compiler flags are in **File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler**